# Validating jwt token in REST api

Tags: amazon-web-services, authentication, jwt, authorization, amazon-cognito

I have a doubt regarding the jwt token validation done by the REST api and was not able to find a simple yes/no answer. Assume that everything is being transferred over HTTPS.
I have the following setup

- React app
- REST API
- AWS Cognito that handles the user registration/login

When a user wants to login, then the React app would call the AWS Cognito api and validate the credentials. If valid, Cognito will send back a jwt token (that will contain the necessary meta data) that can be passed to the REST API. Now I see two options

1. the backend verifies that the jwt token was not altered using the rfc spec. If valid, the api extracts the necessary meta data and continues to process the request
2. The backend verifies the validity of the jwt token, **but also calls the Cognito service to verify the metadata in the token**.

I think that since everything is handled over HTTPS and the fact that its hard create a valid token then the first point is enough. There is no need to have an extra call over the wire. Am I wrong ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the following question from softwareengineering.stackexchange.com which pretty much answers my question. [Link](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/357550/verifying-access-token-in-each-service-of-a-microservice-architecture)

The local validation of the JWT token is enough when the token was created with asymmetric encryption.

Comment: but to check the signature you have to know the public key.
The public key you can only receive with an additional call to cognito in the backend.
See: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/decode-verify-cognito-json-token/

Am I missing something?